# Unable to put anchor tag inside HTML code tag

Tags: html

I have a simple "anchor tag" which i am trying to put inside "code tag" to display the anchor tag as it is for tutorial purpose instead of displaying it as a link but it is not working.I am attaching the sample code here for reference

```html
<pre>
<code>
   <a href="/">Kiwi Corp</a>
</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: That works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;`

```html
<pre>
<code>
   &lt;a href="/"&gt;Kiwi Corp&lt;/a&gt;
</code>
</pre>
```

See [HTML entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity)